# Saving multiple public domain livestreams to disk using ffmpeg/vlc some other resource?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

I am trying to save a few days' worths of video from open webcams to disk, so I can run some analytics on them. (for example this [video](https://5ee71ff03d9d1.streamlock.net:4444/EPGD/pps1.stream/playlist.m3u8) of an airport. I have a few hundred of these, plus bandwidth & storage aren't an issue, how would I go about saving the streams for say 2-3 days?

1. I have tried to write a small bit of python code using `pyav` (wrapper around ffmpeg) to open the stream and save keyframes. But it seems the connection gets dropped after an hour or so...
2. I have looked into `ffmpeg -i <some video URL> output.mp4` but it exits abruptly without any error message.
3. I am able to play the videos in vlc, but not sure how I can proceed with saving the videos.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

ok, not sure why this is voted to getting closed, but I thought of providing the solution/workaround I came up with for any others in my situation:

```
def save_stream(url):
    try:
        cmd = "youtube-dl -f worst {} --retries infinite --continue --hls-use-mpegts".format(url)
        # print(cmd)
        ydl_process = subprocess.check_call(cmd.split(" "))
        print("[*] launched: ",ydl_process)

    except Exception as e2:
        print("[!] e2: ",e2)
    return
```

Using youtube-dl to save the stream to disk saves to a .part file. The `--hls-use-mpegts` flag is important so you can copy the `.mp4.part` file elsewhere and rename it to `.mp4` and it would play using vlc or others.